# How do I find the mean of this problem?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

$$
  F(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
    0,\quad x < 1 \\
    \frac{x^2-x}{2}\quad1 \leq x \leq 2 \\
    1, \quad x > 2
  \end{cases}
$$

How would I find the mean in this problem? Can somebody help me get started? Thank you

Comment: Note that $F_X$ is continuous. Do you know how to find $f_X$ from $F_X$? Once you know $f_X$, do you know how to find the mean $E_X[X]$? This tells you the answer.

Comment: No I do not, can you give me a guide please?

Comment: You should know the basic relationship between $F_X$ and $f_X$. There are two equivalent ways to write it: $F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)dt$ or, equivalently, $f_X(x)=F'_X(x)$.

Comment: Can you show me the first step?

Comment: Then to find the expected value of anything, integrate it against $f$ over the real line. In particular, $E_X[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tf_X(t)dt$.

Comment: what do all these variables mean exactly? T is?

Comment: Do you know how to take the derivative of the function $F_X(x)$ you wrote? That's the first step. It gives you $f_X(x)$. $F_X$ is defined piecewise, so take the derivative of each piece separately to get another piecewise definition of $f_X$ as $F'_X$.

Comment: What exactly do I derive? There are three equations there.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $$F'(x) = 
  \begin{cases}
    0,\quad x < 1 \\
    \frac{2x-1}{2}\quad1 < x < 2 \\
    0, \quad x > 2
  \end{cases}$$

Comment: Let me try this, one second

Comment: So I integrated from 1 to 2 x^2-x/2 and I got 1, what do I do with it?

Comment: That's the mean isnt it!!

Comment: I guess you are confused by piecewise defined functions? Okay, suppose you had a function $g$ with $g(x)=$ for all $x$, a constant function. Then its derivative is just $g'(x)=0$. Easy enough. Now if you had a different function $h$ with $h(x)=(x^2-x)/2$ for all $x$, you can easily compute that $h'(x)=(2x-1)/2$ for all $x$. Then, a third function $k$ with $k(x)=1$ for all $x$ is constant again so it has $k'(x)=0$ for all $x$. Now make a new function $F$ that chooses between $g(x),h(x),$ and $k(x)$ depending on whether $x<1,1\leq x\leq2,$ or $x>2$. Put the derivatives together in the same way.

Comment: Is 1 the mean? .

Comment: I think you integrated wrong, that's not what I got. Try it again, without looking at your first attempt. After integrating, you should be evaluating $\frac13x^3-\frac14x^2$ between $1$ and $2$, right?

Comment: I integrated (2x-1)/2 from 1 to 2, is that correct?

Comment: No, what you said the first time was the right integral to compute (maybe you had a parenthesis error, check again). You should integrate $x\cdot(2x-1)/2$, which is $(2x^2-x)/2$ before integrating, from $1$ to $2$. Be careful about the parentheses, the whole thing has $2$ in the denominator

Comment: Is m(x) 19/12? I tried

Comment: Yes, that's what I got. Good for you!